# Error Connecting to apple push server running on JBoss

Tags: java

The java source run in my local jboss 7.1 server delivers the apple push notification to my  device. When i try with the local server url the connection gets refused.  Below is my jboss local server log.  I cannot detect the issue since it runs good in production server but not in local server.

ServerLog:

```
13:17:14,787 ERROR [stderr] (mohitsending_notification_for_ondemand_ios) Info: Apple push notification: Error in push notification.
13:17:14,787 ERROR [stderr] (mohitsending_notification_for_ondemand_ios) javapns.communication.exceptions.CommunicationException: Communication exception: java.net.UnknownHostException: gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com
13:17:14,787 ERROR [stderr] (mohitsending_notification_for_ondemand_ios)    at javapns.communication.ConnectionToAppleServer.getSSLSocket(ConnectionToAppleServer.java:158)
13:17:14,787 ERROR [stderr] (mohitsending_notification_for_ondemand_ios)    at javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager.initializeConnection(PushNotificationManager.java:106)
13:17:14,803 ERROR [stderr] (mohitsending_notification_for_ondemand_ios)    at javapns.notification.transmission.NotificationThread.runList(NotificationThread.java:215)
13:17:14,803 ERROR [stderr] (mohitsending_notification_for_ondemand_ios)    at javapns.notification.transmission.NotificationThread.run(NotificationThread.java:199)
13:17:14,803 ERROR [stderr] (mohitsending_notification_for_ondemand_ios)    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
13:17:14,803 ERROR [stderr] (mohitsending_notification_for_ondemand_ios) Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com
13:17:14,803 ERROR [stderr] (mohitsending_notification_for_ondemand_ios)    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
13:17:14,803 ERROR [stderr] (mohitsending_notification_for_ondemand_ios)    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
13:17:14,819 ERROR [stderr] (mohitsending_notification_for_ondemand_ios)    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
13:17:14,819 ERROR [stderr] (mohitsending_notification_for_ondemand_ios)    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
13:17:14,819 ERROR [stderr] (mohitsending_notification_for_ondemand_ios)    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:618)
13:17:14,819 ERROR [stderr] (mohitsending_notification_for_ondemand_ios)    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:407)
13:17:14,819 ERROR [stderr] (mohitsending_notification_for_ondemand_ios)    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:88)
13:17:14,819 ERROR [stderr] (mohitsending_notification_for_ondemand_ios)    at javapns.communication.ConnectionToAppleServer.getSSLSocket(ConnectionToAppleServer.java:155)
13:17:14,819 ERROR [stderr] (mohitsending_notification_for_ondemand_ios)    ... 4 more
```

Comment: I edit your title since it was very confusing. Please check if you found the new one correct, but please do not  simply copy and paste log error in the title in the future!!